# Where is HttpRequestBase?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My solution (which is a copy of another one) is reporting an error because it cannot find `HttpRequestBase`.

My code has references to `system.web` and `system.web.mvc`.

Does this class still exist in MVC 1.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this class was part of the System.Web.Abstractions dll. Try adding a reference to that.

Answer (score 1):

System.Web.Abstractions, you'll also need a reference to System.Web.Routing in an MVC project

Answer (score 1):

You can get the full source code of asp.net MVC from http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet FWIW